# android studio - upgrade firebase-ui 0.6.0 to 2.3.0 or latest version

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebaseui

When i trying to build and sync my project with firebase-ui 0.6.0 its all working fine. But when i tried to sync the project with newer version for example - 2.3.0 i am starting to get errors.

some ideas?

**this is my level-application build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mybudgetcontrol.mybudgetcontrol"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.2.0'

    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is my Root-Level :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my AndroidManifest-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mybudgetcontrol.mybudgetcontrol" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the Errors i get when upgrading

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:design:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
    is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.2).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at [Compatibility with Firebase](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries)

If you are using firebase-UI, then the latest version of firebase supported is 11.0.4, But your project is using 11.2.0 which is not supported yet.

So I recommend you to change your firebase version until the next update of firebase UI

Comment: Thanks, 
But Even when i change the version to -

  `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'`
    `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'`
    `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'`
   `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'`
    `compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.3.0'`
same error....

Comment: @doronhine - you need to specify the versions for more of the dependencies.  The link faruk gave has a section "Upgrading Dependencies" - you'll want to read that.  There's no need to wait for the next version of FirebaseUI to upgrade the transitive dependencies.